# How to auto-populate multiple columns based on an index of random 1's and 2's

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have changed this question and the correct working answer to reflect explicitly the solution for my exact problem.

This is for accounting purposes. I'm trying to create a debit and a credit table so that I can keep track of payments and have balanced books for my business partner.

I thought to try `=if(1, value)` in the credit and debit tables however I will get a whole lot of cells of FALSE return values when it discovers values of 2 and vice versa which is not practical.

I have rows of information which I designate a type either 1 or 2. For example:

| type | description | amount | date | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | cable | 50 | 12 May | 1.0mm flat |
| 1 | payment 001 | 30 | 24 May |  |
| 2 | plugs | 10 |  | 8mm size |
| 2 | bits and pieces | 15 |  |  |
| 1 | payment 002 | 20 | 30 May |  |

I have a debit and credit columns in another sheet so what I want to happen is I want each line of the first table and any new line added thereafter sorted into a credit column and a debit column automatically.

| Description | Date | Comment | Credit type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| payment 001 | 24 May |  | 1 | 30 |
| payment 002 | 30 May |  | 1 | 20 |

| Description | Date | Comment | Debit type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cable | 24 May | 50 | 2 | 1.0mm flat |
| plugs |  | 10 | 2 | 8mm size |

I understand that there must be formula in the credit and debit type cells.
I need some kind of sorting system.

Comment: So having a think through it, perhaps VLOOKUP could work?
I would: 1.) scan A2:A the first table for 1's and 2's. 2.) if a row of cells in the credit and debit tables are empty, populate it with the first true value found and then 3.) if a result has already been referenced, look for the next value.
But here you would have a spiderweb of cross-referencing 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @marikamitsos and theartsnettutors with the earth for giving me confidence to resolve this problem and giving me the tools to figure it out for myself.

The best tool to use is QUERY using the SELECT function and then selecting the columns from the RAW data table in the order that you want the data printed:

RAW data:[image]

Solution for CREDIT table:
[image]

Solution for DEBIT table:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do that.

If you need just one table use

```
=SORT(A2:C8,1,1)
```

OR EVEN

```
=QUERY(A1:C8,"where A is not null order by A",1)
```

[image]

If you need two tables just use it twice

One can also use

```
=QUERY(A1:C8,"where A=1 order by A",1)
```

AND

```
=QUERY(A1:C8,"where A=2 order by A",1)
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the proposed answer? Why `VLOOKUP`. No need to complicate things

Comment: By the way. Do you need 1 or 2 tables? You mention *"I'm trying to create a debit and credit table..."*

Comment: I hadn't seen this until now. Let me examine it. Why so impatient? 
Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: *"Why so impatient?*" You asked for it, you got it. Sorry. Next time I will delay my answers :)

Comment: Your answer is USEFUL and CORRECT because you pointed me to the SORT function. You also created the correct result with the QUERY function. To build upon your answer, if one were to create the same result as the QUERY function fo my requirement using the SORT function one may use the FILTER function additionally. P.S. You are nicer to give a working solution than to be bitter about receiving open feedback 

Comment: How did you get E2 and E3 to reflect correctly using QUERY?
I want to quote the row, not just the column.

Comment: No bitterness. I always enjoy a good tease. As for the filter alternative you are correct. As mentioned *"Many ways to do that"* About the `E2` and `E3`.... What do you mean?

Comment: Please refresh the edited question

Comment: https://ibb.co/Ry7wmTB

Comment: Now I am really lost. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: How did you have "payment 001" and "payment 002" reflect correctly in the query which returned only A=1  in this pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag8Np.png

Comment: That is how a `QUERY` works. You can change to `=QUERY(A1:C8,"where A=1 order by B",1)` or even `=QUERY(A1:C8,"where A=1 order by C",1)`. Or you may want the very simple `=QUERY(A1:C8,"where A=1",1)`. Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions)

Comment: Could you please share your test sheet? 

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1luDPMmrEjnJPNc6vM5h2BDWV2Q87ihoZ40s9FdoK0Cs/edit?usp=sharing

Editing in progress

Comment: How do you cross reference "order by C" or "order by B" if you use multiple sheets?
I get error "Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: E"

Comment: Yes I am back on stack ⭐️

Comment: "and even upvote it"
Awesome, will do, but only in two days as per the rules of this community platform.